# DiscordJS - Is there a way to restard a reaction collector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Super quick question. I am wondering if there is a way to "restart" a reaction collector. I am currently using a reaction collector in my event planner bot to add a user to a list depending on how they react. For example, If I react with a thumbs up, it adds me to the list of people attending. I want it to reset itself back to 1 thumbs up afterwards (just the bots reaction) so it can then wait to collect another users reaction. The reason for this is because I want it to continue running until an event occurs. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do a little bit of doc reading because I'm not familiar with the `ReactorCollector` type, and it seems there are plenty of ways of cracking this nut, but I'd like to think I've found an elegant solution using event listeners. (I don't know how you would initialize your collector but for testing purposes I did mine whenever any random message was sent. Obviously don't do this).

I don't know if you meant to reset after 1 user reacted, or after an arbitrary point.
Here is how to reset after each reaction and keep track of who reacted.

```js
let attendees = []; //array of users who are attending
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    message.react(""); //add the bot's reaction so other users can easily click it
    rc = new Discord.ReactionCollector(message, reaction => { //create a new collector, with a filter to only collect emojis that are thumbs up.
        return (reaction._emoji.name == '');
    });
    
    rc.on("collect", (reaction, user) => { //create an event listener for when a reaction is added to this collector
        if (user != client.user) { //if not the bot's reaction
            console.log(`${user} reacted`);
            attendees.push(user); //add user to attendees array
            reaction.users.remove(user); //remove their reaction
            console.log(`Removed ${user} from reaction after they reacted`);
            console.log(`Attendees are now: ${attendees}`);
        }
    });
});
```

Output after one user reacts:

```
<@ID1> reacted
Removed <@ID1> from reaction after they reacted
Attendees are now: <@ID1>
//ID removes for privacy purposes
//the Attendees list will continue to grow with every reaction
```

Whenever you want to stop collecting reactions, you can call `rc.stop(OPTIONAL_STRING_REASON)`
If you wanted, you could do something directly after calling `rc.stop()` or you can use another event listener!

```
rc.on("end", (collections, reason) => {
   console.log(`Stopping collection because ${reason}`);
});
rc.stop("The poll is now over!");
```

---

If you wish to let everyone react until some arbitrary occasion then get all the users and remove their reactions:
(This is very similar to the last method so I haven't left comments)

```js
let rc = undefined;
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith("new")) {
        message.react("");
        rc = new Discord.ReactionCollector(message, reaction => {
            return (reaction._emoji.name == '');
        });
        rc.on("end", async (collection, reason) => {
            console.log(`Stopping collection because ${reason}`);
            let thumbsup = collection.get("")
            let users = await thumbsup["users"].fetch(); //we have to "wait" to get all of them!
            users.each((user, id) => {
                if (user != client.user) { //dont count the bot
                    console.log(`${user} is attending!`);
                    //here is where you could add your users to some array
                    thumbsup["users"].remove(user); //remove their reaction
                }
            });
        });
    } else if (message.content.startsWith("end")) {
        rc.stop("Times up!"); //stop the collector
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! This makes sense, thanks a ton! I'll try implementing this into my program. :)